# SharePoint 2010 Designer Workflow Query

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am new SharePoint designer 2010 and creating workflow in SharePoint.

I have an approval workflow set up in SharePoint that fires as a document is uploaded to a library. This simply sends a notification via email to a user to let them know they have been assigned as a reviewer for the document that has been uploaded. The user then reviews and approves the document.

As the above works, I want to extend the workflow so that the reviewer is sent an email 28 days before the document is due to be reviewed. (this is essentially going to be used as a prompt to get the user to look at the document before the review date comes around.

My approval workflow is name 'Competency Approval' and the review workflow is named 'Competency 28 Days Review'

Please see below the workflow that im using for the review process (Attachment). I want this to fire after the approval workflow has been completed and the status of that document has been set to approve.

Regards Betty
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going off the assumption that Competency 28 Days Review runs after Competency Approval. If so, try the following.

Add a field to your library titled CompReviewDate, set the field type to Date and Time.

In your Competency Approval workflow you will want to set the CompReviewDate field to the desired review date.

The Competency 28 Days Review workflow would then be modified to only run when an item is changed. Set the first Action of the workflow to **Wait for Field Change in Current Item**.  Set the field value to Approval Status, the next selection will be **to equal**, and value will be **Approved**. Below the current action, add a Pause until Date action. For the **this time** selection, select CompReviewDate.

From there, you should be able to add the remaining steps to complete the workflow.

One thing to note, when you create the variable to calculate review date, make sure you set the variable type to Date and Time.

Let me know if you have any questions.